# C++ screen partition

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I want to partition the output screen into two parts (just like frames do it in HTML). So that one part may remain fixed and display some content which is updated based on input received from the other part.

I do not wish to venture into GUI stuff therefore OpenGL, SDL etc are ruled out (I wish to do it in command line mode). I have Borland C++ with `graphics.h` support, but it is just too old to carry on.

What alternatives do I have at my disposal (If not `C++`, a solution in `C` will also be Ok.)

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: Borland C++ with graphics.h - Wow, that's really... retro :))

Comment: @Oli I am using Windows (GCC). A cross platform will be appreciated

Comment: @Armen But some retro have a dull blue flavor to it

Comment: Use `ncurses` -- always with the `ncurses`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at curses-like libraries like [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/).

Other than that, you may use [ANSI terminal escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) to control the cursor on a text window, this may be quicker if what you are doing is simple, otherwise use PDCurses and it will handle the escape sequences for you.

Comment: I was toying with it for quite sometime yesterday and it seems PDCurses is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) / NCurses.

Comment: Isn't `curses` deader than Borland C++? ;-)

Comment: Dead? Not dead, just *very* stable. I only use software that's not been updated in the last 5 years - this way, I don't have to deal with vendor upgrade issues :-)